# React MUI Tree does not display updates unless clicking a child

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My React MUI tree doesn't behave as I expect. Simply press one of the "add" buttons, and it adds a tree item . In general it works. The child gets added properly, but it does not display initially. The newly added item ONLY shows up when I click another sibling on the tree, and then it pops up. Clicking on the root node does nothing. In fact, if I initialize the tree with only the root node and no children, I can never get the newly added child node to display because I have no sibling node to click on for it to trigger the display.

The child nodes are appending to the ROMItems variable properly, but the tree itself just doens't seem to refresh with the new item automatically.

My app.js code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import RomItem from './components/RomItem'
import RomTree from './components/RomTree'
import ChangeDriverForm from './components/ChangeDriverForm';
import { isCompositeComponent } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const ROMItems =  {
    nodeId: 'root',
    label: 'New Epic',
    type: 'Epic',
    children: [{
      nodeId:'child',
      label:'Child Epic',
      type: 'Epic',
      children: [{
        nodeId:'child2',
        label:'Child Epic',
        type: 'Epic',
        children: new Array()}]
    }]
  };

const App = () => {
  const [v1Items, setV1Items] = useState(ROMItems);

  const addChildHandler = (enteredChild) => {
    const newArray = ROMItems;
    newArray.children.push(enteredChild)

    setV1Items(newArray);
    console.log(v1Items)

  };
   
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <ChangeDriverForm/>
      </div>
      <div>Rom Panel4</div>
        <RomTree
          onAddChild = {addChildHandler} 
          nodeId = {v1Items.nodeId}
          label = {v1Items.label}
          type = {v1Items.type}
          children = {v1Items.children}
        ></RomTree>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and my RomTree code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
//import RomItem from './RomItem'
import { TreeItem, TreeView } from '@mui/lab'
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore'
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight'

function RomTree(props){
    const [selectedTreeNode, setSelectedTreeNode] = useState('root');

 
    function treeNodeSelect(event, nodeIds){
        setSelectedTreeNode(nodeIds)   
        console.log({selectedTreeNode})     
    };

    function epicButtonHandler(event){
        const newEpicNode = {
            nodeId: Math.random().toString(),
            label: 'Child Epic',
            type: 'Epic',
            children: []
        }
        props.onAddChild(newEpicNode);
    };

    function backlogButtonHandler(event){
        const newBacklogNode = {
            nodeId: Math.random().toString(),
            label: 'Child Backlog',
            type: 'Backlog',
            children: []
        }
        props.onAddChild(newBacklogNode);
    };
    const renderTree = (nodes) => (
        <TreeItem
                key={nodes.nodeId} 
                nodeId={nodes.nodeId}
                label={nodes.label}>
                {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
                    ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
                    : null}
        </TreeItem>
      );
    return(
            <div >
            <TreeView
                defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
                onNodeSelect={treeNodeSelect}
                aria-label="controlled"
                alignment="left"
                sx={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}>
                    {renderTree(props)}
                    
            </TreeView>
            <button onClick={epicButtonHandler}>Add Epic</button>    
            <button onClick={backlogButtonHandler}>Add Backlog</button>    

            </div>            
    );
}

export default RomTree;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your child is not displaying when the button is clicked is because you need to make a copy of `ROMItems` before pushing a new child. This way react knows to re-render when `v1Items` changes.

```
const addChildHandler = (enteredChild) => {
    // const newArray = ROMItems;  // instead of this
    const newArray = {...ROMItems} // use this
    newArray.children.push(enteredChild)

    setV1Items(newArray);
    console.log(v1Items)

  };
```

Here's a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-tree-does-not-display-updates-unless-clicking-a-child-6ld6cl)